# Use xarray to save DataArray as geoTiff, without using ram memory

Tags: python, gis, python-xarray, geotiff, rasterio

I need to modify a very large geoTif file (over 200GB), however when I save it my code crashes as it loads the file in memory. The code looks like this.

```
import xarray as xr

#  open the file
ds = xr.open_rasterio('file.tif')

# modify here
.....

# this part uses too much memory and gives me the problem
ds.rio.to_raster('output.tif')
```

Is there any way to save the file as a tif, without loading it all in memory?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! [rioxarray supports dask arrays](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/html/rioxarray.html#rioxarray.raster_array.RasterArray.to_raster), so this should work, unless your scheduled tasks blow up the memory. what's in `# modify here`? we need to see all your code to diagnose the issue, ideally as a [mre].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the [multi-worker parts](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/dask_read_write.html) with little bit modification on the parameters for both reading and writing function.

for example:

```
import xarray as xr
ds = xr.open_rasterio('file.tif', chunks=True,lock=False)

# your modification
.....

# Multiple worker
ds.rio.to_raster('output.tif', tiled=True,lock=Lock("rio", client=client))
```

or

```
# multithreaded
ds.rio.to_raster('output.tif' , tiled=True, lock=threading.Lock())
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For a variety of reasons, [link-only answers are discouraged here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/248627). Please edit your answer and include the main points directly in your question. See [answer].